# i'm a beginner following blender guru's donut tutorial trying to make the icing but when i try to pull down one vertex other vertices spasm out

Tags: vertices

[image][image] I move a vertex down and look around and suddenly i see a bunch of vertices that aren't right.

Comment: Just go back and watch the "tutorial" again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have proportional editing on
try pressing O to turn it off.
(it's also an icon at the top of the viewpoint - a circle with a dot in it.)